# Repeat function for every div on page

Tags: jquery

How would i repeat a function for every div that has an id of lets say of 1.

This is what my html would look like.

```
<div class="main" id="1">
<div class="select" id="1">value</div>
<div class="select" id="2">value</div>
<div class="select" id="3">value</div>
<div class="select" id="4">value</div>
<div class="select" id="5">value</div>
</div>
<div class="main" id="1">
<div class="select" id="1">value</div>
<div class="select" id="2">value</div>
<div class="select" id="3">value</div>
<div class="select" id="4">value</div>
<div class="select" id="5">value</div>
</div>
```

i want to loop through all div's that have the class main and get the value of all the cub classes called select. i keep adding to the page so there could be one main div or there could be 100.

Thanks so much

***EDIT:***
what about something like this.

My html:

```
<div id="status"></div></div>
<div class="main">
<div class="select">value</div>
<div class="select">value</div>
<div class="select">value</div>
<div class="select">value</div>
<div class="select">value</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="select">value</div>
<div class="select">value</div>
<div class="select">value</div>
<div class="select">value</div>
<div class="select">value</div>
</div>
```

And my jquery:

```
$('.main div:nth-child(1)').each( myFunction );

function myFunction()
{
    var value = $(this).val;
    $('#status').append(value);
}
```

for each div with the name main i want to have a function that will get the values of ever div with the class select on the main div its on. and then move on to the next main class.

Comment: I don't know if this is your actual markup, but there are two problems with the ID attributes. They can not start with a number, and an ID can not repeat on the same page. They must be unique.

Comment: Both your inner ids and inner classes are likely redundant.

Comment: Based on the edits you've made, you're getting closer.  If you are trying to get the text "value" that is the in the div, you need to do $(this).html() instead of $(this).val().  val() gives you the value attribute of a textbox or something similar, while html() will give you the html in the selected element.

I would still suggest using $('div.main div:nth-child(1)') instead because it narrows it down to divs first so it's a bit more efficient, but both will technically work.

Answer (score 4):

A valid `HTML markup` needs to have **unique** ids. So don't use multiple ID's. Use classes instead, lets assume you have a class called `one` assigned to multiple elements:

```
$('.one').each(function(){
    $(this).somefunction();
});
```

That code would query all those elements and call a method `somefunction()` on each of them.

See [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple same id's! Also id cannot be number-starting. Add class like "c1", then

```
$('.main .select').each(function(el){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

I'm new to jQuery, so check

Answer (score 0):

Misiur was close but the each method just takes a function with the index and element.  Also I added the div tag before the classes so that it doesn't look at all elements.  Just makes it a little more efficient.

```
$('div.main div.select').each(function(index, el){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: if you dont use the arguments in the each callback function, you can leave them off and simply let `this` be the curent element in the loop.  `('div.main div.select').each(function() { alert($(this).val()); });`

Comment: very true, i was just including it there for completeness because sometimes the index can be useful

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need numbers on each div.

```
$('.main div:nth-child(1)').each( myFunction );

function myFunction()
{
   //operate on $(this)
}
```